# React Native ScrollView not working when trying to scroll down

Tags: react-native, expo

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
                <View style={{marginHorizontal: 10}}>
                    <Welcome/>
                    <Carousel/>
                    <Headings/>
                    <ProductsRow/>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
```

I am trying to include the components wrapped inside the `ScrollView` and it could not work properly when I try to scroll down the screen. Any solutions may help?

Comment: Your code seems fine. Can you create a snack of it with your components. https://snack.expo.dev/

Comment: So use the snack component to wrap over the components?